# Sub-classing ES2015 new data types (e.g. Set) in current browsers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

> Update: The Spring 2016 releases of major browsers (Firefox 45, Chrome
>   49 and Edge 13) will enable class extension by
>   default without any flag or mode.

Class and extension are not enabled by default in almost all [current versions of browsers](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) (incl. Firefox, Chrome and Edge).

When I tried to sub-class `Set` using the "traditional" method below:

```
function Set2() { Set.apply(this, arguments); }
Set2.prototype = ...
```

I get an error: `TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'`.

So how can I create `Set`s with different behaviour without setting properties in each instance?

Edit:

[image: Compatibility]

Comment: Just don't use the "traditional" method. Class constructors can only be called with `new`.  Or as `super`.

Comment: @zeroflagL Per my first paragraph, there's literally no want to extend them currently....

Comment: `class` is supported by Chrome and Edge, by default as you put it. Subclassing built-in types is supported as well.

Comment: "Class and extension are **not** enabled by default"

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the chart you've linked to. Edge: green, Chrome: green in strict mode. Also feel free to test some code in that browsers, if you neither believe the chart nor me.

Comment: @zeroflagL I am really not sure what you looked at, but the chart clearly has them as all red (screen cap above) and both Chrome and Firefox throw error when they encounter the keyword `class`.

Comment: I was referring to Chrome 48 and Edge 13. But even Chrome 46 **does** support classes. It's red with a green triangle(!) because, as I said, the code has to run in strict mode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Subclassing builtins (other than `Object`) does require ES6 `class` syntax. This is no different for `Set` and `Map` than for `Array`.

Comment: Very very sad... Not sure why they would implement something to standard (requires `new`) and leaves out some fundamental part of the standard for later...